# Flash as3 ios: error #2007: parameter possible symbol clash in multiple swfs, abc env must be non-null

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm developing an app for iOs using flash air, version 3.8, this version allow me to load a externals swf with assets, flash professional cs6 and flash builder 4.7

I have some kind of lobby where the user select a differents games. If I deploy the app just with 1 game (1 swf), I would loaded a game without problem

But, If I deploy the app with other games, I would just loaded 1 of them swf, but the other games give me this error:

error #2007: parameter possible symbol clash in multiple swfs, abc env must be non-null

The parameter abcenv doesn't exist in my code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am also getting this error in the same way, creating a lobby for games?

Comment: There seems to be some kind of solution here http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1301638 (probably posted by the same user as the OP). Not entirely satisfactory (okay, not at all satisfactory) but hopefully will be helpful to others using 3.9

Answer (score 0):

I have found exactly the same issue it also happens with AIR 3.9 You can only do this by embedding the game logic into your main menu and constructing classes as you need to. I know this makes the initial part of say your menu heavier.

You can however load in swfs as library assets, if you need this. I think the bug has to do with swfs and a restriction of overlapping classes and the fact that you can only use one Application Domain. But this is my best guess on the underlying restriction with this. If you do find a work around let us know.

Comment: first of all, thanks for your answer
The class that crash is a class from an own library, each game use this library for create their game logic, game logic thats is common for each game... If I fix this issue I'll let you know
And again, thanks for your answer

Comment: Hi, any news on this? I am porting a huge desktop/android app to ios and the common application domain is a nightmare since both swf inherit from the same framework.

Comment: do you have more details on this one?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error and solved it today. After Google I found nothing can help. Now maybe I'm the only person that solved the problem easily. This is my story:

1. Working on a AIR actionscript mobile project.
2. In ad-hoc package for iOS, loading multiple SWF files successfully, **except** two. Those two cause the *"Error #2007: parameter possible symbol clash ......"* error.
3. Found there is a very small difference between the normal SWF and the error one: in the error SWF, one MovieClip is 3D transformed, I saw there are three 3D axis above the MovieClip. Then I deleted the MovieClip from stage and Library and replaced with a new one. Problem solved.
4. Note that I didn't re-name anything, or delete any duplicated things. In fact there are many duplicated things (image file with same name, and MovieClip copied between the SWFs) in the SWF files.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue. The issue is that AIR for iOS has to compile ALL of the external .swfs together, so if there are naming conflicts, that can cause trouble. This especially seems to be a problem if two or more of the .swfs were made from the same cloned .fla, even if one of the files had changes made to it.

In my case, it turned out that there were several unused earlier versions of .swfs in the folder of .swfs to be loaded (such as external_movie-prev.swf). I was able to solve the problem quite easily just by deleting these extra files.

This is a common technique in development, just to rename a previous version of a file and add in a new version to the folder for testing. In normal software development these extraneous versions do no harm. But in the case of AIR for iOS, this situation can cause your app to inexplicably freeze when you try to go a movie that also has an unused previous version in your assets folder. This took me several hours to chase down, so I hope it helps someone else.